# Writing a regular expression for getting all words after a specific charcter

Tags: python, regex

I have a file in which all the lines are in the format `title - news_source`. I want to substitute all the characters after the title for  (whitespace).

So far I only have the pattern as `\s-\s` but don't know what pattern to write for the **news_source**.

Can somebody guide me through the process of writing the regex for the **news_source**. Thanks!

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\s-\s.*)', ' ', s)` ?

Comment: That expression worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match `\s-\s.*` and replace with an empty string.

The `\s` can also match a newline. If you want to match whitespace characters without newlines, you can also use `[^\S\r\n]-[^\S\r\n].*`

```
import re    

s = ("title - news_source\n"
            "Airbnb stock has 15% upside after an 'impressive' earning report, says BofA - Business Insider")
result = print(re.sub(r"\s-\s.*", " ", s))
```

Output

```
title
Airbnb stock has 15% upside after an 'impressive' earning report, says BofA
```

---

If there should be at least a single non whitespace char `\S` at the start of the string, you can use a capture group and use the group followed by a space in the replacement.

```
re.sub(r"^(\S.*)[^\S\r\n]-[^\S\r\n].*", r"\1 ", s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7cvpfG/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vF38Cr)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only match `news_source`, you can do the following:

```regex
\w+_\w+
```

- **\w** : will match any alphanumeric character
- **_**: will match the underscore (_)
- **+**: will make sure there must be *at least one* of such character.

So the regex will match any string that contains:

> at least one alphanumeric character, followed by an underscore, followed by at least one aplhanumeric character.

I guess however, that it will not always contain an underscore.
If you simply want to match anything behind the '-', but only want to get the thing after the space, you can create a *capture group*:

```regex
\-\s(w+)
```

This will match anything after the `-` , and *capture* all alphanumeric characters, if there is *at least one alphanumeric character*!
In your case, it would match with `- news_source`, and capture `news_source`.

But if it were a more complicated string such as: `Title - new source _ with : some , very weird "format"` and you really want to get everything after the `-` , then you would use:

```regex
\-\s(.+)
```

Which would capture: `new source _ with : some , very weird "format"`.
Where the `.` will match any character, except for a line break (`\n` and `\r`).

I'm not sure what exactly you are using to evaluate regex expressions in python, but you should check how you can extract the capture group from a match.

#### Edit:

After your reaction, I now see that you want to simply get rid of the source. That's my bad!

In that case:

```regex
(.+)\s-
```

This will capture the title (everything before  `-`).
I hope the explanation of all the above expressions is enough to understand what this one exactly does. In short: It captures everything before the pattern  `-`.

I will leave the rest of the examples in here as well unless people want me to remove them for clarity.

Comment: ```"Airbnb stock has 15% upside after an 'impressive' earning report, says BofA - Business Insider"```. This is the sample line of text in the file. I want to get rid of all the characters after ```BofA```.